# Geting public holiday to json from google calendar API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-calendar-api

I am trying to get google calendar API data to JSON using reactjs hooks as follows

```
const [data, setData] = useState({ hits: [] });

useEffect(() => {
    getEvents();
}, []);


const getEvents = async () => {
    const result = await axios(
        'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/en.usa#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com/events?key=MYKEEEY',
      );
      setData(result.data);
      console.log(data);
}
```

When I run my app I am getting the following error

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

I have followed all instructions created the app, generated needed credentials.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: after generating credentials you need to pass credentials in requestheader

Comment: @NegiRox can you show it as answer how to do that?

Comment: How did you obtain your API key?

Comment: @ziganotschka through this link here from google docs https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/js

Answer (score 0):

The google docs provide several suggestions to fix this.
https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/errors#401_invalid_credentials

```
401: Invalid Credentials
Invalid authorization header. The access token you're using is either expired or invalid.

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "authError",
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization",
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid Credentials"
 }
}

Suggested actions:

Get a new access token using the long-lived refresh token.
If this fails, direct the user through the OAuth flow, as described in Authorizing requests with OAuth 2.0.
If you are seeing this for a service account, check that you have successfully completed all the steps in the service account page.
```

Your specific error message says "Login Required", so it seems like your issue might be with the OAuth flow. I see that, however, you say:

> I have followed all instructions created the app, generated needed credentials.

If that's the case, it sounds like you might need a new access token.

Comment: How do I use those credentials in my app ??

Answer (score 0):

### You cannot access the Google's holidays calendars with an API key only anymore, see [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/124589446) and [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/149772956)

Instead, you need to obtain the `Client ID` (e.g. by clicking on the [Enable the Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/js) button and subsequently note the Client ID) and you need to use this Client-Id for the creation of credentials / authorization flow.

The process is a bit different in every language and I have not done it in Reactjs. But there are turorials explaining you how to perform the authorization for the Calendar API in Reactjs, e.g. [this one](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/js).